# SDK for Visual Studio 2012 error

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio-2012, sdk, installation

Every time I try to install SDK for windows I get the error that I have no Visual Studio installed. I have Visual Studio Express 2012 both for desktop and web,and the SDK package is for 2012 version. The VS Express is licensed to me. What could be the problem?

Comment: You can't do anything with the VS SDK if you don't have the full version.  Express doesn't support add-ins.

Comment: Any ideas where I can get the full version?

Comment: Let's say I have a win7 OS,with VS installed..I have no chance to develop mobile applications? I must have..let's say that original full version of VS 2012,or eventually,Win8 with Visual Studio for Windows Phone?

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with the VS SDK.  Avoid wildly installing stuff, lots of ways to shoot your foot.  If you want to develop apps for Windows Phone (assuming that's what you mean by "mobile applications") then you'll have no trouble finding the Express edition for that by using Google.  You do have to pay attention to the prerequisites, booting Win8 is a hard requirement.